# How do I make a UIImagePickerController camera not take up the whole screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, uiimagepickercontroller, zbar-sdk

I have a tab bar controller. I want to have a camera always open on one of the tabs, but underneath the camera, you can still see the rest of the tabs. How do I make it so that the camera doesn't take up the whole screen, but is just above the tab bar?

(By the way, to be specific, I'm not actually using a UIIMagePickerController, but the ZBarReader)
Thank you

Comment: Did you try to add it as a sub view to a superview that itself is smaller than the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment was right:
Did you try to add it as a sub view to a superview that itself is smaller than the screen?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't.
You should use `AVCaptureSession` - check out [Erica Sadun iOS 5 Cookbook - Chapter 7](https://github.com/erica/iOS-5-Cookbook/tree/master/C07/05-Camera%20Helper) and it should be pretty easy.